# memcached sometimes holding corrupt data

Tags: memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have been using Memcached (AWS Elasticache) for a while now.

Just today I ran into a situation that I hadn't experienced before. Regularly there is a call to the database for a list of countries and I store this in memcached. This time however the data wasn't stored correctly (I'm not sure why as it has worked fine for months) but after looking over the code & trying code based fixes (assuming something was wrong with the site code) a bounce of the cache fixed the issue. Note: I had bounced memcached the day before so maybe it didn't warm up correctly etc.

My Question is - currently I check to see if the memcached key exists and if it does I use the data. Only if the memcached key doesn't exist do I query the database and populate the key. Do I also need to validate the data somehow to so I can be sure its not corrupt or should this be seen as an infrequent issue (which it is) and left at that.

Also I believe the memcached key didn't have any data in it so maybe just checking if the key is empty is good enough...

Code below:

```
    public $countryList = array();


    // Countries, Country Code, Zip Enabled --- 'generic::countryList::'.$_SESSION['language']'
    public function countryList() {
    $elasticache = new elasticache();
        if(!$this->countryList = $elasticache->memcached->get('generic::countryList::'.$_SESSION['language'])) {

            --- this is where the database query code is

            $elasticache->memcached->set('generic::countryList::'.$_SESSION['language'], $this->countryList, 2592000);
        }
    }
```

I guess confirming the data in the key is correct would required a database call and therefore would defeat the purpose of memcached....

thoughts & ideas?